# pass variables from controller to constructor in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

how is it possible to pass variables from from a controller to the constructor?

```
 function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $info['title'] = 'No title';
    $this->load->view('include/header',$info);
}


function be_cool()
{

    $info['body'] = 'template/becool';
    $info['title'] = 'This is the be cool title';

    $this->load->view('include/template',$info);
}

function be_hot()
{

    $info['body'] = 'template/behot';
    $info['title'] = 'This is the be hot title';

    $this->load->view('include/template',$info);
}
```

im trying to change the titles based on the value defined in the controller. but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. In your `be_cool()` method:

```
$$his->load->view('include/template',$info);
```

Should be

```
$this->load->view('include/template',$info);
```

And also `$his` should be `$this` in your other method.

Comment: i fixed those errors but i still cant seem to pass the title values to the constructor..

Comment: Oh. You are loading the titles into the include/template view, but I suspect you would want them in the header. Instead of loading the header view everytime, please have a look at some template libraries. It'll save you plenty down the line: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template